# How close can you spoof a melody?

Tags: composition

I am scoring a children's dvd and there is a game of "hide and seek," where we want to spoof the Mission Impossible theme. I'm changing bits: the bass line is in triplets and plays different notes at the turn-arounds. This part, I'm not worried about, it sounds different, but implies the original.

What worries me is how closely I can rip off the descending flute line that comes in at about 15 seconds in this [video](http://youtu.be/mWGeRgFa-hI).

Is there room for parody without needing to ask permission? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is always a line between spoofing and copy right infringement.(Especially in the music world.) You may want to seek out a professional's opinion. I've been curious about doing something like this too, in a different medium, however. I have a toll free number (1-877-476-0778) that is for copyright questions and submissions. You can find it off of this website: http://www.copyright.gov/ this is the online presence of the United States Copyright Office. Hope this helps you in your endeavor, and if you find anything out, please let me know! I'd be interested in what you find.